# How to remove lower sash of this window

Tags: windows

See attached picture of top of the lower sash window, I don't see anything to unlock it so I can lift I and remove from track. This window (1st picture) doesn't hold when I lift it open. It drops down. I need to repair or replace channel balance (it is already loose but I can't remove it) but I am unable to remove lower sash to begin with.

[image]

2nd picture shows the other window in same house, that window opens and close fine.

[image]

Comment: Older sashes used to have a removable panel in the channel, about half-way up the window's travel. Though usually buried under 17 coats of paint, that was the access to replace sash cords & re-tie the weights. That looks a bit narrow but it's worth a look. Alternatively, you've to take the inner strip off & swing the window out on any remaining cord [which still means you need to get access to the centre channel.] You shouldn't need to remove a window to change a sash cord.

Comment: I need a picture of the upper part of the window jamb, showing the track that the good sash travels in. There should be what looks like a small sliver of metal there that aids in removing the sashes. The sliver is about pencil wide, and an inch or so long.